# JPA Criteria API predicates for objects in OneToMany relationship

Tags: jpa, jpa-2.0, criteria, criteria-api

Given the following code

```
@Entity
public class Invoice {

  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  @Id
  public Long id;

  @Embedded
  private InvoiceData data = new InvoiceData();
} 


@Embeddable
public class InvoiceData {
  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  public Collection<InvoiceLineItem> lineItems;
}

@Entity
public abstract class InvoiceLineItem {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private Long id;

  @Column
  private String description;
}

@Entity
public class GoodsLineItem extends InvoiceLineItem {

}

@Entity
public class CostLineItem extends InvoiceLineItem {

}
```

How would I write a criteria api query that returns all Invoices with a CostLinesItem that's description is 'TAX'?

I am using the metadata API. I have tried various approaches most of which are variations of the 2 listed below. Any pointers/help or 'go read this's will be greatly appreciated.

Attempt 1 (of many):

```
@Test
public void criteria_api_and_collections() throws Exception {

    CriteriaBuilder builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Invoice> query = builder.createQuery(Invoice.class);
    Root<Invoice> root = query.from(Invoice.class);

    Join<InvoiceData, InvoiceLineItem> lineItems = root.join(Invoice_.data).join(InvoiceData_.lineItems);

    query.where(builder.equal(lineItems.get(InvoiceLineItem_.description), ""));
    List<Invoice> resultList = em.createQuery(query).getResultList();

    System.out.println(resultList);
}
```

Attempt 2 (of a many):

```
@Test
public void criteria_api_and_collections() throws Exception {

    CriteriaBuilder builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Invoice> query = builder.createQuery(Invoice.class);
    Root<Invoice> root = query.from(Invoice.class);

    Join<InvoiceData, InvoiceLineItem> lineItems = root.join(Invoice_.data).join(InvoiceData_.lineItems, JoinType.LEFT);

    Subquery<CostLineItem> subquery = query.subquery(CostLineItem.class);
    Root<CostLineItem> fromLineItem = subquery.from(CostLineItem.class);
    subquery.select(fromLineItem);
    subquery.where(builder.equal(lineItems.get(InvoiceLineItem_.description), "TAX"));

    query.where(builder.in(lineItems).value(subquery));

    List<Invoice> resultList = em.createQuery(query).getResultList();
}
```

Both attempts causes a SQL grammer Exception. An alias is referred to in the resulting SQL that is never created. It looks like the alias should have been assigned to a join in the SQL that does not exist. In other words the InvoiceLineItems are not fetched in the query.

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to make a test right now, but sticking to the [Java EE 6 Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbqa.html#gjiwz), we see that

> Embeddable classes may also contain relationships to other entities or
>   collections of entities. If the embeddable class has such a
>   relationship, the relationship is from the target entity or collection
>   of entities to the entity that owns the embeddable class.

This makes me think that the `Join` Predicate should be defined with the starting Entity `Invoice` instead of `InvoiceData`. And this is supported also by the fact that normally the starting Entity should be the query root itself. I would try with something like this:

```
Join<Invoice, InvoiceLineItem> lineItems = root.join(Invoice_.data).join(InvoiceData_.lineItems);
```

Comment: Thank you for the information. Unless I am misunderstanding it is currently as suggested (excluding the JoinType.LEFT that I have added during the struggle)?

Answer (score 0):

I swapped out Hibernate 4.1.0.Final for EclipseLink 2.0.0 and it worked.